# What is the right way to return the l-value of element of vector?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference

At the beginning, I try as follows

```
class MyClass
{
    vector<int> v;
    int & operator[](size_t idx)
    {
        return v[idx];
    }
}
```

But I found that changing the elements in the vector invalidates the reference or pointer.
so what is the right way to return a l-value of element of a vector?

Comment: How are you using this class?

Comment: The caller of `operator[]` should not save the reference and then try to use it after a vector resize operation (same as for `vector` itself).  If you want to support that behaviour then you'll have to return a proxy class

Comment: The code snippet is fine. "The right way" is to save the index and gets the reference to the element whenever needed.

Comment: Are you keeping pointers/references to elements around?

Comment: "*changing the elements*" does not cause invalidation of the references. Only calling member functions of the vector that could modify its size or capacity do. There is no way to avoid that because resizing the vector could cause movement of the whole vector in memory. If you need stable references even if elements are added or removed, you need to use some other container, such as a `std::list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I found that changing the elements in the vector invalidates the reference or pointer.

It doesn't.

Changing vector's *capacity* does invalidate iterators, references and pointers to elements.

> what is the right way to return a l-value of element of a vector?

Make the vector member `const` and initialize the vector in the constructor. This way the vector cannot be resized after the construction, so that references and pointers to elements do not get invalidated (until the vector is destroyed):

```
class MyClass {
    vector<int> const v;
    static vector<int> createV();
public:
    MyClass() : v(createV()) {}
    int const& operator[](size_t idx) const { return v[idx]; }
};
```

---

Alternatively, the references, pointers and iterators to elements of node-based containers, such as `std::forward_list`, `std::list`, `std::set`, `std::map`, `std::unordered_set`, `std::unordered_map`, do not get invalidates when container size changes. You can use one of those containers instead if resizing the container is necessary when there are existing references to elements.

Comment: I would say "changing the capacity" instead of "size".

Comment: What about changing the capacity without changing the size? I'd say mentioning the capacity is enough.

Comment: Also, suppose MyClass has a member function void f(std::vector<int> v) { _v = std::move(v); } and you call it as follows: MyClass mc; mc.move({1,2,3}); Then, even if the member v has capacity = size = 3, the reference is invalidated. This is just a comment, it does not invalidate your answer :)